# ng-mouseover not showing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have a table and on one of the columns i want some data to be diaplayed on mouseover or on mouseenter but it is isnt working in angular.

```
 <table id="ls-shop-rel-list" class="row ls-shop-list packages" data-per-page="40">
   <thead class="">
     <tr class="row hidden-xs">
                <th>Apply?</th>
                <th><span class="down" data-column="bank.name">Bank</span></th>
                <th><span class="down" data-column="package_name">Package</span></th>
                <th><span class="down" data-column="info_name">Info</span></th>
                <th><span class="down" data-column="monthly_payment">Monthly<br>RM</span></th>
                <th><span class="active up" data-column="interest_rate">Interest<br>Rate</span></th>
                <th><span class="down" data-column="maximum_tenure">Max<br>Tenure</span></th>
                <th><span class="down" data-column="maximum_finance">Max<br>Margin</span></th>
                <th><span class="down" data-column="lock_in">Lock in<br>Period</span></th>
                <th><span class="down" data-column="is_flexi">Full Flexi<br>Loan?</span></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              <tr class="row hidden-xs" ng-repeat="data in loans">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="hidden-xs" id="{{data.id}}"/>
                    <img class="ls-decoration hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" src="http://cdn.app.com.my/assets/button-selected-large-a3480a3ee5f72bf6937d0b95ab38b347.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img style="max-width: 90px; max-height: 35px" alt="{{data.bank_name}}" src="http://static.app.com.my/assets/common/banks/{{data.bank_image}}">
                </td>
                <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                **<td><img class="tip" src="http://static.loanstreet.com.my/assets/common/glasses.png" ng-mouseover="data.notes"></td>**
                <td>{{data.monthly}}</td>
                <td>{{data.effective_rate}}%</td>
                <td>{{data.maximum_tenure}}yrs</td>
                <td>{{data.maximum_finance}}%</td>
                <td>{{data.lock_in_period}}</td>
                <td>{{data.is_flexi}}</td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
```

On the highlighted column, i want on mouseover for it to display the data in data.notes but it seems not to be working. Any clues by anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Your ng-mouseover should be like:

```
ng-mouseover="myMouseOverFuntion()"
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.showDataNotes=false;
$scope.myMouseOverFuntion=function(){
  $scope.showDataNotes=true;
}
```

and finally, in your html:

```
<div ng-show="showDataNotes">{{data.notes}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, css will be a better option here

```
<td class="data-notes"><img class="tip" src="http://static.loanstreet.com.my/assets/common/glasses.png"><span class="notes">{data.notes}</span></td>
```

then

```
td.data-notes span.notes{
    display: none;
}
td.data-notes:hover span.notes{
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for the responses. But i solved it like this

```
<img class="tip" src="http://static.loanstreet.com.my/assets/common/glasses.png" popover="{{data.notes}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter">
```

angular ui-bootstrap popover solved it for me but you must add

```
<script src="scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

to your main.html file then u can call the popover component.